# Java - is volatile required with synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, volatile, memory-model

In the following simple scenario:

```
class A {
  int x;
  Object lock;

  ...

  public void method(){
    synchronized(lock){
      // modify/read x and act upon its value
    }
  }
}
```

Does x need to be volatile? I know that synchronized guarantees atomicity, but I am not sure about visibility though... does lock -> modify -> unlock -> lock guarantee, that after the second lock the value of x will be "fresh"?

Comment: `x` doesn't have to be volatile, but `lock` must be final for sanity.

Comment: Of course, you must read `x` while holding the same lock.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik So if I want to be able to get the latest value of `x` without locking, should `x` be declared volatile?

Comment: @Poison If you write to a plain variable and read it from another thread, you may observe the initial value all the time. On top of that, even if you observe the write, you may not observe any other writes the writing thread made before the one you observed.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry for my unclear question, if a variable is written in a synchronized block, and then another thread calls the variable's getter method (without synchronized modifier), in this scenario, does the variable need to be declared volatile?

Comment: @Poison If you access the variable without taking the same lock, you get behavior as if there weren't any locks to begin with. I can't say if marking a variable volatile will solve the problem you have. It will behave as any other volatile variable that is written and read without any locks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No it does not, because **synchronized** already has a memory barrier inserted after it, so all threads will see the update that the current thread performs, taking into account that the other threads will synchronize on the same lock.

Volatile, just like synchronized, has memory barriers that are attached to it - depending on the CPU, it is store/load/full barrier that ensures that an update from one thread is visible to the other(s). *I assume this is performed with CPU cache invalidation*.

**EDIT**
From what I've just read, the store buffers are flushed to the CPU cache, and this is how the visibility is achieved.

Comment: Where in the JLS is this behaviour described?

Comment: @jarnbjo The Java Memory Model section.

Comment: @jarnbjo this has to do with Java Memory Model, *visibility* is achieved with memory barriers.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks. JLS memory model section seems short and concise, but I can never find the relvant bits that actually help me with real-life situations. If that's not too much to ask, could you point/paste the relevant bit that describes this behaviour?

Comment: @Bober02 if u are in this industry sooner or later you will "meet" Martin Thompson's excellent blog, I'm glad to introduce you to it. :) http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html   Happy reading!

Answer (score 4):

Simplified answer:  If thread A updates a field and then releases a lock, then thread B will be guaranteed to see the update after thread B has acquired the same lock.

Note, "release a lock" means exit a `synchronized` block, and "acquire the same lock" means synchronize on the same object.

Comment: *after thread B has acquired the same lock* that is not true. It does not have to acquire the lock to see the update. Just a simple re-read will be enough

Comment: @Eugene Read the section "Memory Model" in the Java Language Specification, and pay attention to the "happens before" relationship.  If thread A writes a field and then unlocks a mutex, the write "happens before" the unlock.  But if thread B subseqently reads the same field without synchronizing on the same lock, there is no "happens before" relationship:  It is perfectly legal for the JVM to let thread B see a locally-cached, old value of the field no matter how much real-time has elapsed since thread A wrote it.

Comment: Don't be confused by the difference between what your JVM actually does on any particular day with what a correctly implemented JVM is _allowed_ to do.

Comment: I have to admit I always thought that synchronised has a memory barrier inserted after it and that memory will be synched. I still have not found any reference on that but definitely have to sync on the same lock for visibility. Thank you!!

Comment: @Eugene I may have misunderstood what you were saying.  I was imagining a variable that is not volatile, thread A writes the variable inside a synchronized block, but thread B reads the variable without synchronization.  In that case, the new value should be flushed out to memory when thread A leaves the synchronized block; but on some architectures, if thread B runs on a different core, it could still see the old value in its local cache.  I don't know if that ever happens in practice, but the Java Language Spec _permits_ it to happen.